# Add xmlns as an attribute to an element in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to create a xml file with xslt. I need that the first element contains two attribute as followed:

```
<Nomination_Doc release="1"
xmlns="sas:nominate:1">
```

I tried the following code:

```
   <xsl:element name="Nomination_Doc">
   <xsl:attribute name="release">1</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="xmlns">sas:nominate:1</xsl:attribute>
```

but it gives me:

```
<Nomination_Doc release="1">
```

and the attribute xmlns is missing. i did a little research and found out that xmlns is like a reserved word, which is used only to declare a namespace [SOURCE](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/srivastava-namespaces.html). What is the solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and just should literally write

```
<Nomination_Doc release="1" xmlns="sas:nominate:1">
```

in XSLT if you want to create an element whose name and namespace is known when writing the code. `xsl:element` is only needed when you want to compute the element name and/or namespace at run-time.

Comment: wow great, that was easy. I was right now trying it with template.

Comment: Just for completion, the `xsl:element` instruction has an optional `namespace` attribute, so you could do `<xsl:element name="Nomination_Doc" namespace="sas:nominate:1">`. But as noted, this is an unnecessary complication when both the name and the namespace are known in advance.